# Python Value error

Tags: python-2.7, raspberry-pi, subprocess, stdout, flex-paging

I'm getting an error when trying to split a piped output into python.

Error is `need more than 3 values to unpack` although I'm using 8 values

```
import subprocess, sys

from datetime import datetime

from time import sleep as sleep



multimon_ng = subprocess.Popen("multimon-ng -a FLEX -t wav flex.wav",
    stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
    stderr=subprocess.PIPE,
    shell=True)

while True:
        nextline = multimon_ng.stdout.readline()
        flex, mdate, mtime, bitrate, other, capcode, o2, msg  = nextline.split(" ", 7)      # error here
        if nextline is " ":
            print "napping"
        else:
            print mdate + " " + mtime + " " + capcode + " " + msg

        multimon_ng.poll()
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

any help would be great

Comment: Hi @shaggs, I removed the `flex` tag as this is pretty clearly not an Apache Flex question.  I'm not sure how to retag it because I'm not sure what you mean by "flex" in this context.  Is it the Fast lexical analyzer?  Something else?

Comment: @Brian FLEX is also a paging protocol. That how its being used in this question https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLEX_(protocol)

Comment: Oh, I see.  Unfortunately, I don't think we have a tag for that :(

Comment: there isn't and I can't make one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`3` in error message indicated length of iterable in right hand side argument.

Minimal wrong examples:

```
a, = []  # ValueError: need more than 0 values to unpack
a, b = [1]  # ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
a, b, c = [1, 2]  # ValueError: need more than 2 values to unpack
# etc ...
```

Minimal correct examples:

```
a, = [1]
a, b = [1, 2]
a, b, c = [1, 2, 3]
```

Smallest change to fix and expose issue would be to wrap unpacking iterable in try-except block.

```
while True:
    nextline = multimon_ng.stdout.readline()

    if not nextline:
        print "napping"
    else:
        try:
            flex, mdate, mtime, bitrate, other, capcode, o2, msg  = nextline.split(" ", 7)
        except ValueError:
            print "invalid line", nextline
        else:
            print mdate + " " + mtime + " " + capcode + " " + msg

    multimon_ng.poll()
    sys.stdout.flush()
```

As you can see, I also moved check for empty line before unpacking. If line is empty, unpacking would also fail.